# jupyter notebook not launching

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter notebook on my laptop about a month ago. It was working fine till now. But today when I tried to start jupyter notebook it is not launching. Just nothing happens. Even No error message is displayed.

Note that I installed Jupyter Notebook on my machine, not using Anaconda Distribution.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSIpJ.png)

Comment: Any output from `jupyter --help` or `jupyter notebook --help`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the actual command you're using; don't provide just a link to an image.

Comment: Does your `python` command work ? If so, could you also try `python -m jupyter notebook`?

Comment: yes my `python` command works and `jupyter --help` gives output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now my problem is solved.

I uninstalled jupyter notebook and python 3.6.5 and installed python 3.7.0 and jupyter notebook. It solved my problem.